Flycheck doesn't recognize my ROOT installation
I want to use Emacs as an IDE to write C++ code for a physics laboratory class, mainly using the data analysis framework CERN ROOT.
I installed ROOT in a conda environment with:
mamba create -c conda-forge --name my_env root llvm llvm-tools clang clang-tools cmake make libclang

The relevant part of my init.el looks like:
;; lsp
(use-package lsp-mode
  :straight t
  :bind(
    ("C-c l" . lsp-keymap-prefix)
    )
  :hook (
         ;; ((c++-mode) . lsp)
         (lsp-mode . lsp-enable-which-key-integration)
     )
  :commands lsp
  )

(use-package lsp-ui
  :straight t
  :commands lsp-ui-mode
  :after lsp
  :hook (lsp-mode . lsp-ui-mode)
  :custom ((lsp-ui-doc-enable t)
       (lsp-ui-doc-show-with-cursor t)
       (lsp-ui-doc-position 'at-point)
       (lsp-ui-sideline-enable t)
       (lsp-ui-sideline-show-diagnostics t)
       (lsp-ui-sideline-show-hover t)
       (lsp-ui-sideline-show-code-actions t)
       (lsp-ui-peek-enable t)
       (lsp-ui-imenu-enable t)
       )
  )


(use-package helm-lsp
  :straight t
  :commands (helm-lsp-workspace-symbol)
  )

(use-package lsp-treemacs
  :straight t
  :commands (lsp-treemacs-errors-list)
  )

;; Language completion

(use-package company
  :straight t
  :hook ((prog-mode LaTeX-mode) . company-mode)
  )

(use-package company-box
  :straight t
  :hook (company-mode . company-box-mode)
  )

(use-package flycheck
  :straight t
  :hook (c++-mode . flycheck-mode)
  )

;; C++

(use-package irony-mode
  :straight t
  :ensure t
  :hook (
     (c++-mode . irony-mode)
     (c-mode . irony-mode)
     (objc-mode . irony-mode)
     (irony-mode . irony-cdb-autosetup-compile-options)
     )
  :config (
       (setq irony-cdb-clang-options
         (append (list "-I/home/myself/miniforge3/envs/my_env/include") irony-cdb-clang-options))
       )
  )

(use-package company-irony
  :straight t
  :after (company irony)
  :config (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-irony)
  )

(use-package flycheck-irony
  :straight t
  :hook (flycheck-mode . flycheck-irony-setup)
  :after irony
  )


(use-package treemacs-projectile
  :straight t)

(use-package clang-format
  :straight t
  :bind ("C-c C-f" . clang-format-buffer)
  :hook (c++-mode . clang-format-on-save-mode)
  )


My questions are:

I wrote this set-up code with the aid of ChatGPT, but I don't trust it that much. Indeed I fear there are many redundancies and that I got some stuff pretty wrong. For example, do I still need lsp-mode and lsp-ui if I have irony configured? Or does irony take care of lsp-ui features for itself? (Keep in mind that I also use Emacs for writing documents in LaTeX).

Emacs (more properly, flycheck) can't find the ROOT headers, and every time I #include (say) TCanvas, the line where I made the declaration become red. How do I make Emacs or whatever recognize my ROOT installation?



flycheck doesn't care about where your headers are; the checkers/linters/tools it calls do care. Make sure they're configured properly, and are working in the context of whatever "project" your working on. work on one thing at a time in your ~/.emacs.d/init.el. reduce it to the absolute bare minimum. flycheck has excellent documentation


I wrote this set-up code with the aid of ChatGPT, but I don't trust it that much

First of all, lsp-mode needs no initial setup. You can just put a
(use-package lsp-mode
  :defer t
  )

and it will work. It comes by default with all kinds of bells and whistles enabled, you may want to follow this official guide to disable anything you don't like.
With that out of the way…

For example, do I still need lsp-mode and lsp-ui if I have irony configured? Or does irony take care of lsp-ui features for itself?

It's the other way round: you don't need irony. irony does things similar to lsp modes (whether lsp-mode or eglot). It existed before LSP standard became a thing and LSP-related modes appeared. The difference is that irony only handles C/C++, whereas lsp-mode handles dozens of languages. So these days setting up a lsp-mode or eglot is more useful.
Thus you can remove everything irony-related from your config.
Can't say much on the lsp-ui setup you got as I don't use it, but my basic advice is to try to remove some variables and see if anything you need disappears or not. I presume AI has enabled for you lots of features that are default anyway.

Emacs (more properly, flycheck) can't find the ROOT headers, and every time I #include (say) TCanvas, the line where I made the declaration become red. How do I make Emacs or whatever recognize my ROOT installation?

Now that we had ironed out that you don't need no irony in your config, this question comes down to lsp-mode and the lsp server you're gonna use.
There are multiple popular servers, one example is clangd. If you have it installed (so it's available in your $PATH), it will be picked up automatically upon enabling lsp in .c or .cpp file.
Now, the question becomes "how do I make sure clangd sees the headers". Again, there are multiple ways, but the easiest one is just to make your build system (which is completely unrelated to your Emacs and to clangd for that matter) assemble a compile_commands.json file for you. It should contain all the necessary directories and options, so when clangd is started at the root of your project, it will search for compile_commands.json file either there or in build/ subdirectory; which, if found, should provide clangd with the expected paths to headers on your system.
